# add command to check text and attribute

Tags: cypress

I have to write a command where i have a textfield which should have a value and i have to check that the field is disabled or not. The disabled part can be case per case that is sometimes i do not need this assertion  but the value check will always be there.
This is what i have done so far:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value) => {
 cy.get(selector).within(() => {
    cy.get('input').should('have.value', value)
})
```

This is the html of a disabled button:

```
<input disabled="" placeholder="my-field" type="tel" value="0,00" inputmode="numeric">
```

and this for one which is enabled:

```
<input placeholder="my-field" type="tel" value="1 200,00" inputmode="numeric">
```

A field which is enabled is a field in which i can input text.
A field not enabled is one which cannot input text, when a calculation is done the field will be updated by itself.

How do i put the disabled condition in it?

thank you

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the element when disabled/enabled?

Comment: @agoff 
``` <input disabled="" placeholder="my-field" type="tel" value="0,00" inputmode="numeric">```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that information? And can you be explicit about what a disabled or enabled button looks like?

Comment: @agoff pls let me know if any other info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to add an additional parameter to your command. We can then use that parameter to conditionally change the assertion between `'have.attr'` and `'not.have.attr'`. Below, I'm using a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to accomplish that.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled) => {
  cy.get(selector).within(() => {
    cy.get('input').should('have.value', value);
    cy.get('input').should(isDisabled ? 'have.attr' : 'not.have.attr', 'disabled')
  });
});
```

Additionally, if you had an overwhelming amount of one checks vs. the other, you could make the `isDisabled` parameter optional/nullable, and make that "default" check the false result of the ternary. (If switching `'have.attr'` to the false statement, it may make sense to rename `isDisabled` to `isEnabled`)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?)
// with isDisabled false
cy.checkTextAndAttr('foo', 'bar', false);
// with isDisabled true
cy.checkTextAndAttr('foo', 'bar', true);
// with isDisabled undefined -- the `.should()` evaluates the same as false (both undefined and false are not true)
cy.checkTextAndAttr('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: is there any reason why the line gets highlighted when i use? as in Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?)

Comment: Is there an error message in your IDE?

Comment: The compilation fail and it says syntax error

Comment: `Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?)` on its own is not correct syntax. That was shorthand to show the function. Look at the more robust implementation above, as that is correct.

Comment: If i add the function like this: Cypress. Commands. add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?)  => {

Comment: If i add the function like this: Cypress. Commands. add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?)  => {... Then add my if else condition should not the syntax be okay?

Comment: It should. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: It says syntax error , then ../../commands.js unexpected token

Comment: isDisabled?) => {           
                   ^

pointer on the bracket

Comment: `Cypress.Commands.add('checkTextAndAttr', (selector, value, isDisabled?) => {})` does not give me any syntax errors in my IDE, I'm not really sure why yours would.